# Is there a way to have an app-icon switcher like Android 2.x in Windows 8.1?

Tags: 8.0, 8.1, multi-tasking

One thing a little annoying about Windows-phone is that the switcher shows a whole screen for every recent app. On Froyo phones, if you hold the home button you'd get a recent-apps-switcher that showed up to 8 icons on one screen, no need to thumb left and right to see which screen was the app you wanted.

Is there any option/workaround that will give the old Android-2.2 style behavior, when holding the back button to switch apps?

Answer (score 4):

This part of the Windows Phone OS is locked down. There is no way for any app to change this behavior.

Comment: That's sad. I wonder if any rooted apps have this, or will Windows 10 have it?

Comment: @NoBugs No, Windows 10 will not likely have it as it's a secure operating system like iOS.

Comment: Sideloaded apps do not have additional API's they can use. As @NeilTurner says, this is by design.